# if...else...if statement (command not found error)

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this loop?

[image]

The error that I have is on the line 107 (first line of the loop). It says:

> [V2016057174800: command not found.

I am trying to associate two the same filename from two different documents (if that makes sense).

Comment: `[` is a command itself, and needs a space after it (you'll also need a space before the `]`). Please paste in text instead of using a screenshot, too.

Answer (score 5):

Your formatting is very strange!
You probably want to fix that first to make this code somewhat readable!
That said, your problem is the lack of spaces around `[` and `]`.

These characters `[` `]` are actually just shorthand for the command `test`.
You should change the first line to read as follows:

### in [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))

```
if [[ "$L1Aname" == "$filename" ]]; then
```

or

### in [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shells

```
if [ "$L1Aname" = "$filename" ]; then
```

inside both of which examples, each character maters:

For example spaces: there need to be spaces around `[` and `]`.

Plus notice the subtle difference between [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) in the double / single `=`.